# model.predict_generator and model.evaluate_generator return completely different accuracies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have trained VGG as a 10-class classifier on 100 epochs, and this is the train/validation accuracy.
[image: train/validation accuracy]

Also, I wanted to test the model on a hold-out test set, so I evaluated it like so:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/domat/solo-dataset/test/',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False
)

steps = 3616 // 32 

loss, accuracy = model_vgg_imagenet_dropout.evaluate_generator(test_generator,
                                             steps = steps,
                                             workers = 4,
                                             use_multiprocessing=True)
```

When I print the results I get (1.4021655139801776, 0.802820796460177), which is similar to what I expected.
However, when I try to manually evaluate it through the model.predict_generator, I only get **13**% accuracy.
Following is the code for manually evaluating it (the generator is the same object):

```
predictions = model_vgg_imagenet_dropout.predict_generator(test_generator,
                                             steps = steps,
                                             workers = 4,
                                             use_multiprocessing=True)

y_pred = np.zeros(len(predictions))

for i, p in enumerate(predictions):
  max_index = np.argmax(p)
  y_pred[i] = max_index

# the y_pred array should contain the class index of each sample, as defined by test_generator.class_indices

y_true = test_generator.classes
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

I don't understand where I'm making a mistake, it seems correct to me.

Edit: when I manually observe the results from model.predict_generator() and map the softmax values to the class index, it literally outputs like 3 or 4 classes most of the time.

Comment: What's your decision boundary? I suggest you argmax then feed your results into any evaluation.

Comment: Yes, I find the highest probability from the softmax output and consider it as the predicted class. I suppose that's top-1 accuracy?

Comment: Is your target a one-hot encoding? Also check how Keras calculated the accuracy, there may be difference in how you and Keras did that job. With currently provided information a lot of things may go wrong.